# Classifying the function as even or odd in restricted domain

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f:(-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow[0,1], f(x)=\cos(x)$

Clearly this function is even as $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$

Suppose if we defined $f$ as $f:[0,\pi)\rightarrow[0,1], f(x)=\cos(x)$

How do we now classify $f$ as even or odd since in this given domain we will not be able to calculate $f(-x)$ for all $x\in[0,\pi)$?

I think that since we can't check for condition of $f$ being even or odd , we should report our answer as $f$ is *neither even nor odd in this domain.*

Am I right?

Comment: Even /odd functions are defined only only on domains that are symmetric about $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of silly to ask about function if it's odd or even when the whole domain included on one "side" of the real line. It's like asking about function being injective where the domain is formed by 1 point. I think that logicly speaking, your claim is correct, but it has no real information we can get about the function.